# Angular 6 call service function inside ngOninit

Tags: typescript, svg, angular6

I am trying to run a service inside ngOninit but I am getting error. I have a svg map and I am calling elements of map using :

```
 let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")  as HTMLObjectElement;
```

In my component.html file I am adding this code to get svg map:

```
<object data="assets/img/bihar.svg" id="biharsvg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

And I am calling this id biharsvg in my ngOninit using this code:

```
let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")  as HTMLObjectElement;
   a.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
      var wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");
      wchamparan.onclick = function() {
      alert("hello");
      this.SvgService.barchart()
    }
 })
```

Everything work fine I am getting alert message onclick. I am trying to a function of my service inside that click event When I add this.SvgService.barchart()  outside addEventListener  it is working but when I add this inside onclikc of addEventListener I am getting error.

My first error is inside visual code :

```
[ts] Property 'SvgService' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
any
```

And inside console I am getting this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barchart' of undefined
```

Edit when I am using this code:

```
this.SvgService.barchart()
```

inside onInit it is working problem happen only when I am trying to add this inside onclick or addEventListener

What should I do in this case:

Comment: Use an arrow function instead of a normal function in your call to `addEventListener()`.

Comment: Can you explain more where and how should I add  addEventListener(). –

Comment: See this [Typescript Tutorial](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) to learn more about the benefits of using arrow functions. Here, the this scope was different, so that your object was not found. "The reason why this works is the reference to this is captured by the arrow function from outside the function body."

Comment: @MatthiasSommer can you be more specific I am unable to call my service function inside click event

Comment: Try this 

`a.addEventListener("load", () => {
      var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
      var wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");
      wchamparan.onclick = () => {
      alert("hello");
      this.SvgService.barchart()
    }`

Comment: Yes this is working it also worked in my services. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` inside the `addEventListener()` method refers to the element from which the event has been triggered.

You need copy your `class` referenced `this` to another variable (something like `that`)and use inside `addEventListener()`

```
const that = this;
let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")  as HTMLObjectElement;
   a.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
      var wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");
      wchamparan.onclick = function() {
      alert("hello");
      that.SvgService.barchart()
    }
 })
```

Comment: This is working can you add one more thing I am trying to do this inside service I am updating the question. Just help